# MassTransit RabbitMQ Streams

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I would like to try the RabbitMQ Streams with MassTransit.
The objective is to define the configuration for only a subsets of the queues.

I managed to add the queue arguments when the consumer is configured using the code :

```
rabbitmqConfigurator.SetQueueArgument("x-queue-type", "stream");
```

It does creates the queue has expected.

However, the command is sent from an another process (which is not consuming), and when I try to send the command, the app hangs and I can see on the rabbitmq an error message :

```
operation queue.declare caused a channel exception precondition_failed: inequivalent arg 'x-queue-type' for queue 'MyCommand' in vhost 'vhost_1': received 'classic' but current is 'stream'
```

I assume I should also define the queue argument in the producer process, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're seeing is because you're trying to explicitly send to a queue from another process. Try sending to the exchange instead (using `exchange:name` as the endpoint address).